# Continuous function with '0' functional value at integer points

Tags: real-analysis

Let f: $\mathbb{R}$->$\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that f(i)=0, for all i$\in$$\mathbb{Z}$ . Which of the following statements is always true?

A. Image(f) is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

B. Image(f) is open in $\mathbb{R}$

C. f is uniformly continuous

D. None of the above.

I can only see that Option B is not true. The correct option is D, whereas I am unable to eliminate A and C options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function 
$$
f(x) = x^2 \sin(\pi x).
$$
The range is the entire real line, which is open.  This function also fails to be uniformly continuous.

EDIT: I don't know what I was thinking, but $f(x)$ is not a counterexample to A, only C.

To get a counterexample for A, we need to first think of a continuous function whose range is not closed.  Let $g$ be any continuous and monotone
function with the property that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x) = 0$ and 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 1$, but such that $0<g(x)<1$, so that the image is $(0,1)$ (which is not closed).  For example, one could set $g$ to be the cumulative distribution function of the gaussian:
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-y^2/2}\,dy.
$$
Now consider the function $f(x) = g(x)\sin(\pi x)$.  The range of $f(x)$ is now $(-1,1)$ and is in particular not closed.

Comment: How to think about such questions? Graphically or theoretically?

Comment: Actually, I have just realized that my answer is incorrect.  The range of this function is open, and also closed.  I will edit the answer now.

Comment: But to reply to your comment -- I would say that I mostly think graphically about these sorts of things.  Continuous functions are extremely flexible, so a drawing is almost as good as an example.  There is just the last step of turning a drawing into a definition of a function, and that just takes practice.